# Excel: Format rows in sheet B based on value in sheet A

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

How do I shade an entire row on one Excel sheet when an "X" is placed in column "A" of the same row in a different sheet in the same workbook?

Comment: This question and (more importantly) answer describes what you are trying to do, I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280579/coloring-complete-row-based-on-values-from-columns

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color cell based on text value](http://superuser.com/q/315868/354511), [Changing cell color based on its contents](http://superuser.com/q/450801/354511), and about 180 others.

Comment: The possible unique aspect of this is applying conditional formatting based upon a trigger cell on another sheet.

Comment: Yes, this is not a duplicate because the condition refers to a cell on another sheet, which requires some extra steps that won't be found in answers to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this small macro a try:

```
Sub ShadyRow()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        If s1.Cells(i, "A").Value = "X" Then
            s2.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Apply the following "*Use a formula to determine which cells to format*" Conditional Formatting to all the cells on `Tab 2` for which you wish the shading to be applied:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet 1'!R"&ROW()&"C1",FALSE)="X"
```

Replace `Sheet 1` with whatever the actual sheet name is for `Tab 1`, and define the formatting as you desire in the Conditional Formatting dialog.

**Notes**

- The single quotes around the sheet name are only required if the sheet name has one or more spaces in it.
- The `FALSE` argument to `INDIRECT` tells it to use R1C1-style references, rather than A1-style references.
- Using an appropriate string concatenation construction, one could easily point the Conditional Formatting formula to a cell on this or another sheet, so that the sheet that determines the highlighting (`Tab 1` here) could be changed by the user by editing the relevant cell containing the target sheet name.